# Is there anyone that can help me with Balanced Brackets in Python using Stack?

Tags: python, linked-list, stack

Modify the chkBracketsBal function so that the caller can supply the brackets to match as arguments to this function. The second argument should be a list of beginning brackets, and the third argument should be a list of ending brackets. The pairs of brackets at each position in the two lists; that is, position 0 in the two lists might have [ and ], respectively. You should be able to modify the code for the function so that it does not reference any literal bracket symbols, but just uses the list arguments. (Hint: The method index returns the position of an item in a list.)

```
begList = ["[","{","("]
endList = ["]","}",")"]

def chkBracketsBal_v2(myStr):
    stk = LinkedStack()
    for i in myStr:
        if i in begList:
            stack.append(i)
        elif i in endList:
            pos = endList.index(i)
            if ((len(stack) > 0) and
                (begList[pos] == stack[len(stack)-1])):
                stack.pop()
            else:
                return "Unbalanced"
    if len(stack) == 0:
        return "Balanced"
    else:
        return "Unbalanced"


string = "[]{}"
print ("Beginning List: " ,string[1], string [3] )
print ("Ending List: ", string[0], string[2])
print("Exp: ",string,"-", check(string))
```

This is my answer, I don't know how to print the value of the beglist which are being used in the string

Comment: the instructions are confusing... it doesnt ask you to check if they are balanced and it says it should accept three arguments

Comment: *"I don't know how to print the value of the beglist which are being used in the string"*: what do you expect to be output? What if the input is `[[[[[]]]]]]`? There is nothing in the assignment that says you need to print `[[[[[[` or `]]]]]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Append them to a list while parsing the string and return the list along with the result string like this.

```
begList = ["[","{","("]
endList = ["]","}",")"]

def chkBracketsBal_v2(myStr):
    stack = LinkedStack()
    open_brackets = []
    for i in myStr:
        if i in begList:
            stack.append(i)
            open_brackets.append(i)
        elif i in endList:
            pos = endList.index(i)
            if ((len(stack) > 0) and
                (begList[pos] == stack[len(stack)-1])):
                stack.pop()
            else:
                return "Unbalanced", open_brackets
    if len(stack) == 0:
        return "Balanced", open_brackets
    else:
        return "Unbalanced", open_brackets


string = "[]{}"
print ("Beginning List: " ,string[1], string [3] )
print ("Ending List: ", string[0], string[2])
result, blist = chkBracketsBal_v2(string)
print("Exp: ",string,"-", result)
print(blist)
```